# Customize axis displays on Google Motion Chart

Tags: google-visualization

I have a Google Motion Chart embedded in a website.

Is there a way in the embed code to add '%' signs next to each value on the x/y axis?

So instead of just:

```
10, 20, 30, 40,
```

it would display as:

```
10%, 20% 30% 40%?
```

Comment: Probably add it as a title for that axis.

Comment: Yes - I've added it as a title, but this particular client would also like each value to display a % sign. I'm not sure it's even possible in a motion chart, but thought I'd throw it out there in case anyone else knows for sure.